# MySQL & PHP: summing up data from a table

Tags: php, mysql, html

Okay guys, this probably has an easy answer but has been stumping me for a few hours now.

I am using PHP/HTML to generate a table from a MySQL Table.  In the MySQL table (TimeRecords) I have a StartTime and EndTime column.  In my SELECT statement I am subtracting the EndTime from the StartTime and aliasing that as TotalHours.  Here is my query thus far:

```
$query = "SELECT *,((EndTime - StartTime)/3600) AS TotalPeriodHours
    FROM TimeRecords
    WHERE Date
    BETWEEN '{$CurrentYear}-{$CurrentMonth}-1'
    AND '{$CurrentYear}-{$CurrentMonth}-31'
    ORDER BY Date
    ";
```

I then loop that through an HTML table.  So far so good.  What I would like to do is to add up all of the TotalHours and put that into a separate DIV.  Any ideas on 1) how to write the select statement and 2) where to call that code from the PHP/HTML?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Take a look at SUM in sql. Use ajax to call the PHP script from html.

Comment: @BenniKa Why on earth would you use ajax? There's absolutely nothing in the question to suggest he's using ajax and it's not necessary anyway.

Comment: @liquorvicar i meant: if he want to call it from the html site, because of 2).

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
$query= "
    SELECT ((EndTime - StartTime)/3600) AS Hours, otherFields, ...
    FROM TimeRecords
    WHERE 
        Date BETWEEN '{$CurrentYear} - {$CurrentMonth} - 1'
        AND '{$CurrentYear}-{$CurrentMonth} - 31' ";

$records =mysql_query($query);
$sum= 0;
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($records))
{
      echo"$row['otherFields']";
      echo"$row['Hours']";
     $sum+=$row['Hours'];
 } 

 echo" Total Hours : $sum ";
```

Comment: This would be the manual tally method I mentioned. If iterating all rows in PHP is undesirable, then running a separate Sum() query is an option.

Comment: Thanks so much!  I was so focused on getting MySQL to do the work I totally forgot about PHP

Answer (score 0):

Just use a single query with a **Sum()**. You could also manually calculate it if you're already displaying all rows. (If paginating or using LIMIT, you'll need a separate query like below.)

```
$query = "
    SELECT Sum(((EndTime - StartTime)/3600)) AS SumTotalPeriodHours
    FROM TimeRecords
    WHERE 
        Date BETWEEN '{$CurrentYear} - {$CurrentMonth} - 1'
        AND '{$CurrentYear}-{$CurrentMonth} - 31'
";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in the same query if you have a unique id using [GROUP BY WITH ROLLUP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/group-by-modifiers.html)

```
$query = "
    SELECT unique_id,SUM((EndTime - StartTime)/3600) AS TotalPeriodHours
    FROM TimeRecords
    WHERE Date BETWEEN '{$CurrentYear}-{$CurrentMonth}-1'
      AND '{$CurrentYear}-{$CurrentMonth}-31'
    GROUP BY unique_id WITH ROLLUP
    ORDER BY Date
";
```

In this instance the last result from your query with contain NULL and the overall total. If you don't have a unique ID you will need to do it in PHP as per Naveen's answer.

A few comments on your code:

- Using SELECT * is not considered good practice. SELECT the columns you need.
- Not all months have a day 31 so this may produce unexpected results. If you're using PHP5.3+, you can use

  $date = new DateTime();
  $endDate = $date->format( 'Y-m-t' );

The "t" flag here gets the last day of that month. See [PHP docs](http://uk.php.net/DateTime) for more on DateTime.